# Getting the value from Dropdown and pass it to URL address of Dynamic Dropdown as parameter

Tags: dynamic, drop-down-menu, orbeon

I have a simple Dropdown ( `control-30`) with

> 'label1'...'labelN'

that has values

> 'val1'...'valN'

Selecting, let's say, `label2` to pass the corresponding `val2` to a dynamic dropdown with Requested URL `http://example.com/demo?code=????` (e.g. `{$control-30}`, etc.) How can I do that or there is no way inside the contro-settings dialog box to do that but only inside the form as a code. Can you give an example? For example, a solution would be like :  `http://example.com/demo?code={$control-30}`

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple : `http://example.com/demo?code={../control-30}`